# "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" on saving multiple DataFrames in 1 excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having an error output trying to save multiple DataFrames in a singles excel file.
Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

path  = ['path1.txt', 'path2.txt', 'path3.txt']

data = []
data = [pd.read_csv(i, sep=" ") for i in path]
 
with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name= path[i].replace(".txt", ""), index=False)
    writer.save()
writer.close()
```

What I'm doing wrong? I've tried many solutions, but didn't worked.

Comment: just remove `writer.close()`, the `with` context will take care of closing the file for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context manager in the `with` clause closes the file when you exit the block. The additional explicit `writer.close()` call is redundant and causes this error. Remove it and you should be OK.